# OOP, what is the best practice to use two different Retrofit implementations in a big project?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns, retrofit2

I have a situation where I need `Retrofit` instance with caching , but most cases I use default Retrofit instance, I know that caching require using `OkHttp` client, but what I need is an elegant way to use those two instance without replicating code ..

I thought that I may use `Dagger` to handle this, but it's an old project and I'm trying to enhance it one part at a time.
any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just create two instances of Retrofit. One with cache & one without cache.

```
 public static <S> S  createService(Class<S> yourApiClass) {

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return return retrofit.create(yourApiClass);

    }

 public static <S> S  createServiceWithCache(Class<S> yourApiClass) {

            //add your cache logic here
            return return retrofit.create(yourApiClass);

        }
```